# gRPC JSON transcoding : using repeated fields in query parameters

Tags: json, http, request, grpc, transcoding

I'm trying to make a request via Swagger using JSON transcoding, but I'm encountering an error when I use a repeated field parameter in my request. The error message I'm receiving is:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeNww.png)

I've attached my code snippet below for reference. Can someone help me figure out what's causing this issue and provide a solution for making a request with a repeated field parameter using JSON transcoding in Swagger?

Here's my code snippet:

```cs
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/greeter/{name}/{ids}"
    };
  }
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
  IdsRequest ids = 2;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

message IdsRequest {
  string id = 1;
}
```

My request:

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDRrr.png)

Note: I am using a very simple example just to shorten the code for this question.

Comment: See [gRPC Transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api#grpc-transcoding) specifically: "The path template may refer to one or more fields in the gRPC request message, as long as each field is a non-repeated field with a **primitive (non-message)** type". `ids` is a message type in your example.